# How does Programs and Features List Programs?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, regedit

I'm interesting in knowing what sources the Windows "Programs and Features" is influenced by. I've found that removing `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*` will remove an item from the list, but I've also removed program registries from other places in the registry that have the same effect. So, does anyone know specifically what registry locations it feeds from?

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: You could use process monitor to monitor when you open programs and features to see what registry files it accesses, it is a powerful too and requires some expertise to use it but will give you what you need....https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx

Comment: Any version of windows that uses the registry, it shouldn't matter. I'll check that out, but I am looking for a definite answer however hard that might be to find. Why did my question get down-voted? :(

Comment: Downvotes are just opinions, your question should include any research effort on your part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a 64Bit Windows and also use 32bit programs, you also have to look in the `WOW6432Node` node

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

and remove the entries there.